# vb6 Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer) does not work

Tags: forms, vb6, taskmanager

I am trying to catch when Microsoft Windows Task Manager is closing the application. I know there are these UnloadMode possibilities:
    '0   The user has chosen the Close command from the Control-menu box on the form.
    '1   The Unload method has been invoked from code.
    '2   The current Windows-environment session is ending.
    '3   The Microsoft Windows Task Manager is closing the application.
    '4   An MDI child form is closing because the MDI form is closing.

Code:

```
Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer)
'[do saving]
End Sub
```

But it does nothing when I close application using task manager. If I close using Close button - it saves all what I need. Where is the problem?

Comment: I guess you checked to see that the event fires whatever way you close the application maybe by sticking a msgbox UnloadMode in before any other code in the event?

Comment: you mean add msgbox inside Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer)? The same result. No message if using task manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you terminate via the processes tab in task manager no further code gets executed whereas if you terminate via the applications tab it does.

See this answer on another forum:

By user "vbface" (2003-12-29) :

> Killing a process in the Task Manager immediately (or so) kills the program where it is, with no further events firing. It is like putting an END statement in VB. No cleanup, no closing processes, just a termination of the app.

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=131604